# Are custom fonts allowed to be listed in the drop down for UILabels?

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I loaded 2 custom fonts (.otf) and placed them in the application's plist file, checked to make sure that they were in the Summary | Build Phases | Copy Bundle Resources section.

When adding a UILabel in the storyboard, I cannot see the that font in the drop down.

Do all the labels need to be done programmatically ***only***? For example:

```
UILabel *myLabel;
[myLabel setText:@"Some Text"];
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gloucester MT Extra Condensed" size:24.0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, yes that is the way it is.  They will show up if you use rich text instead of plain text on your label but they don't survive the trip.

Comment: So could I still create the UILabel in the storyboard and set the font programmatically in the class? Or does the NIB override the class. I'm thinking something like my 3rd line in the code in a viewDidLoad or viewWillAppearMethod? `[self myLabel setFont:[...]`

Comment: The NIB will set it, but you can override it provided you do it in or after `viewDidLoad`.  Make sure you know the exact name or it will fail.  Fonts are an unbelievable pain....Confirm your fonts with `[UIFont familyNames]` and `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:]`